# How do I create a transition between 2 border styles?

Tags: html, css, border, transition

So how can I transition one border style to another. Say fade a dotted border into a solid one on hover. Impossible to do with standard CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I already solved this and thought it might be useful to share it for others too.

Here's a working example of how you can transition 2 border styles from one to the other.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  border: 5px dashed green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  position: relative;
}

div::before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 40px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
div:hover::before{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px green;
}
```

DEMO:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwYPrx